# Emoji in SFMC Mobile Push Notification

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobilepush, push-notification

I am trying to include Emoji in my Push notifications.

When I use a REST API tool such as ARC tool and trigger Push notification to a device, I see the Emoji in my notification. For example:

POST https://www.exacttargetapis.com/push/v1/messageContact/TEMPLATEID/send

{
    "devicetokens":["xxxxxxxxxxxx"],
    "Override": true,
    "MessageText": "\ud83d\ude08 This Holiday Season, get 30% off all products"
}

When I trigger the above using REST tool, I do see the Christmas tree Emoji in my Push notification but when I try to include the same message text in my Outbound API triggered Mobile Push notification, it doesn't work - I just receive the Unicode in my notification.

I even tried implementing it through https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_gc_dynamically_add_emoji_to_a_message.htm&type=5 but no luck.

Can anyone help me figuring this out.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried simply cutting and pasting the emoji into the text field as opposed to using the Unicode?

Comment: Thank you @BillMote, I got the same response from SFMC support. They asked me to copy and paste it directly in the message. SFMC supports all the emoji's available here https://emojipedia.org

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste the emoji directly into the message text entry field.